# Making MCQ order randomizer bash script that calculates total score

Tags: bash, terminal, logic

This is an MCQ script in which I am trying to read the MCQs from another file that is present after the bash code below. The bash file is displaying those MCQs in a random order and based on that order, the MCQ answers will be marked. The user will select the answers and a final score will be calculated and displayed in the end. I can't understand why the shell gives an error in this *code*. There must be some error I am unable to point out.

```
#!/bin/bash

score=0
correct=5
wrong=1
a=1
b=1
c=1
d=1                                                                                
booler1=false; booler2=false; booler3=false                                        
for (( i=1;i<=30;i++ ))
do
                                                #rndr=(( ( RANDOM % 3 )  + 1 ))
rndr = shuf -i1-3 -n1

    if [ rndr==1 && booler1==false] then
    booler1=true
    b=5;a=1;c=1;d=1;
    for (( num=4; num<=8; num++ ))
            do
            sed ''$num'q;d' bnsaFil
            echo -e "\n"
            done
    fi

    if [ rndr==2 && booler2==false ] then
    d=5;c=1;a=1;b=1
    booler2=true
    for (( num=10; num<=14; num++ ))
            do
            sed ''$num'q;d' bnsaFil
            echo -e "\n"
            done
    fi

    if [ rndr==3 && booler3==false ] then
    booler3=true
    c=5;a=1;b=1;d=1
    for (( num=16; num<=20; num++ ))
            do
            sed ''$num'q;d' bnsaFil
            echo -e "\n"
            done
    fi

read -p "Enter a, b, c, or d: " answer

case "$answer" in
a)
score=$((score+a))
;;
b)
score=$((score+b))
;;
c)
score=$((score+c))
;;
d)
score=$((score+d))
;;
*)
echo "There is no selection: $answer"
;;
esac

done

echo -e "\n your Score: $score"
```

The other file from which the MCQs are being read is:

```
#**.txt file**
#MCQs file

"Qs\. What is that which is correct?"
 "a). tiger"
 "b). lion"
 "c). cheetah"
 "d). zebra"
                         //correct: b
Qs/. Which place is best?
 "a). srilanka"
 "b). bangladesh"
 "c). india"
 "d). pakistan"
                        //correct: d
Qs/. Which degree is expensive?
 "a). law"
 "b). engineering"
 "c). medical"
 "d). none"
                         //correct: c
```

(**note:** I added 30 iterations instead of 3 because I haven't yet came up with a logic through which I can make MCQ display each once with three iterations only, along with being random. For this, it'll require to remove that number from the random no. generating list.)

If these code errors are removed, the script shall work.

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.